# Lambda function failing, no logs generated

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm playing with this [PDF To Image converter](https://github.com/legalthings/lambda-pdf-thumbnail) and I've cloned the repo, run `npm install`, changed this section:

```
var s3EventHandler = new S3EventHandler({
  region: 'my-region',
  outputBucketName: 'my-bucket-name'
  s3: s3,
  resolution: 72
});
```

Renamed it exports.js, zipped up the the js, node_modules folder, package.json and event.json (I've also tried with both of these jsons removed) and uploaded it into my Lambda function. The s3 trigger has been created and so far is working fine.

I've had multiple test failures because it couldn't find a either the async module and tmp module, which I've moved to the top level and it seems to fix it (however it doesn't complain about the other modules that it requires and aren't in the top level).

In the test it complains s3 is not defined which I'm sorta lost with as there isn't a lot of details with it. I thought it could be that I'm just running test so the s3 trigger with itself is missing.

When I upload a pdf into the bucket, Lambda reports that it runs but fails. Going into CloudWatch Logs says there is no log stream for it. I've checked the IAM role and it has permissions to `CreateLogStream` and `PutLogEvents` (it was the templated IAM policy).

How can I get my logs working to find the problem? Or what can I do to fix the s3 not defined issue which is my only clue atm? It could be related to the top level module requirement however that doesn't seem consistent as only some modules need to be at the top level?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like "CreateLogGroup" Permission is missing from what you have mentioned. The following permissions are required for lambda to write logs to CloudWatch

```
"logs:CreateLogGroup", "logs:CreateLogStream", "logs:PutLogEvents"
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed it as it was in a different section, yes it does have that policy.